# How do I query for a boolean value using ActiveRecord::TypedStore in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

What is the syntax for querying a boolean value using ActiveRecord::TypedStore ([Github Link](https://github.com/byroot/activerecord-typedstore))?

Trying the below doesn't seem to work? and throws the following error:

**PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: text = boolean**

```
current_user
  .companies
  .where("holiday_request_settings ->> :key = :value",
         key: "enable_holiday_requests",
         value: true)
```

If I try the following I get no results:

```
current_user
  .companies
  .where("holiday_request_settings ->> :key = :value",
         key: "enable_holiday_requests",
         value: "true")
```

The company currently has the following data:

```
holiday_request_settings: {
  "enable_holiday_requests"=>true,
  "holiday_allowance_days"=>20
}
```

This is the code on the Company model:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :holiday_requests

  typed_store :holiday_request_settings, coder: JSON do |s|
    s.boolean :enable_holiday_requests, default: false
    s.integer :holiday_allowance_days
  end

end
```

Migration for the Company Model:

```
add_column :companies, :holiday_request_settings, :json
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How does the model and migration for that table (and columns) look like?

Comment: @SebastianPalma updated to show model and migration